# Tiny persistent storable class

Tags: python, database

I would like to have a *minimal* storable class in Python that I can use as ORM. I quite thinking my approach is bad, but I would like to have your opinion.

I do not want to use SQLAlchemy or PeeWee as it is too complex for my application.

I wrote a `Model` class from which I can derivate storable items:

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
from typing import NamedTuple

class NotNull:
    pass


class Column(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    type: type = str
    default: any = NotNull


class Model():
    __tablename__: str
    __attrs__: [Column]
    __primary_key__: str
    __hidden__: [str]

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(cls, '__tablename__'):
            cls.__tablename__ = cls.__name__.lower()

        if not hasattr(cls, '__hidden__'):
            cls.__hidden__ = []

        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Fill attributes in order
        for attr, arg in zip(self.__attrs__, args):
            if attr.name in self.__hidden__:
                continue

            if not isinstance(arg, attr.type):
                raise ValueError(f"{attr.name} has not type {str(attr.type)}")

            setattr(self, attr.name, arg)

        # Fill conditional attributes
        for attr, value in kwargs.items():
            u = [attrs for attrs in self.__attrs__ if attrs[0] == attr]
            if not u:
                continue
            type = u[0].type

            if not isinstance(value, type):
                raise ValueError(f"{attr} isn't type {str(type)}")

            setattr(self, attr, value)

        # Fill remaining attributes with None
        for attr in self.__attrs__:
            if getattr(self, attr.name, None) is None:
                if len(attr) == 2:
                    raise ValueError(f"{attr.name} has no default value")

        self._post_init()

    def _post_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def _db(cls):
        table = getattr(cls, '__tablename__', cls.__name__.lower())
        return TinyDB(data_dir(table + '.json'))

    @classmethod
    def all(cls):
        """Get all users from the database."""
        return [cls(**user) for user in cls._db().all()]

    def save(self):
        """Save a new user into the database."""
        pk = self.__primary_key__
        pk_value = getattr(self, pk)
        if self.find(pk_value):
            query = getattr(Query(), pk)
            self._db().update(self.to_dict(), query == pk_value)
            return

        self._db().insert(self.to_dict())

    @classmethod
    def truncate(cls):
        cls._db().truncate()

    @classmethod
    def find(cls, name):
        """Find a user into the database."""
        user = Query()
        results = cls._db().search(user.name == name)
        return cls(**results[0]) if results else []

    def __repr__(self):
        data = ','.join([
            '='.join([attr[0], str(getattr(self, attr[0]))])
            for attr in self.__attrs__ if attr[0] not in self.__hidden__
        ])
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({data})'

    def to_dict(self):
        return {attr[0]: getattr(self, attr[0]) for attr in self.__attrs__}

    def to_json(self):
        return to_json(self.to_dict())
```

For example if I want to store articles:

```
class Article(Model):
    __attrs__ = [
        ('name', str),
        ('type', str, 'sausage'),
        ('price', float, 0.0)
    ]
    __primary_key__ = 'name'
```

Then I can use it as follow:

```
>>> Article('apple'^, 'vegetable', 1.12).save()
>>> Article.all()
[Article(name=apple,type=vegetable,price=1.12)]
```

Would it be better to use `shelve`?

Comment: A truly tiny persistent class is just a normal class serialised via pickle. Why not just do that?

Comment: Seems like `Article` could be a `dataclass`.  `dataclasses provide a way to specify fields, types, and values and `__init__()`, `__repr__()`, and `asdict()` methods. So `Model` just needs to provide the database methods.